# Which projections emphasise the Northern Hemisphere, other than Mercator?

Tags: coordinate-system, mercator

I'm working on a project where I have data points in the UK, US, France/Italy, Hong Kong and Japan. I want to show a world map with mini charts at each of these locations.

For this project, it makes sense to use a map projection that emphasises the northern hemisphere, so that I have more space for the charts.

Should I just use Mercator?

Or are there other projections that are also/more suited to rendering the northern hemisphere?

Comment: I don't believe that taking advantage of Mercator distortion (what you call emphasis) makes it suitable for *honestly* displaying the northern hemisphere. I'd look into an equal area or compromise protection.

Comment: What on Earth does "emphasise the northern hemisphere, other than Mercator?" actually mean? You need to be more specific as to the purpose of the map. Why not just ommit the southern hemisphere?

Comment: @martinf Many people would understand this to be a request for map projections in which the stated portions of the world are all displayed and are done so with as little distortion (of certain properties) as possible. It is usually implicit that local distances, small shapes, and small area measures should be rendered faithfully, but it is allowed that larger distances, large shapes, and directions may undergo considerable distortion.  Richard, this raises many questions: exactly what geometric properties of the features do you want to show accurately?

Comment: @whuber - I think you're reading a lot into the question that isn't necessarily there. I thought maybe "emphasise" meant "make larger" which Mercator certainly does (but does equally to northern and southern hemispheres. I also thought the Q was a reference to Arno Peters' misguided rant against cartography. Without more detail from the OP, there's much we can assume or guess at.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for this comment - yes, I was looking for a projection where local distances and small shapes in these countries were rendered accurately, and where it didn't matter if they weren't rendered so accurately in the southern hemisphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Lambert's Conformal Conic, it has its standard parallel at 50 & 20 degrees North which is ideal for the countries you list. Plus I think it looks pretty cool.